# Proxy vpn traffic into socks or second vpn

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, socks, xl2tpd

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server that I have running xl2tp and openvpn as a VPN server. However, I want the server itself to be connected to either a SOCKS Proxy or another OpenVPN connection. That is:

```
client --> server --> vpn or socks server --> internet
```

Right now, if I perform a `curl` or `wget` request from the server's terminal (to, say, `https://api.ipify.com/`), it's traffic is clearly going through the second vpn or socks (I've tried both).  However, if I connect a client to the server over l2tp or openvpn, and then try the same `curl` or `wget` from the client, it's traffic is exiting from the server directly, rather than router through the second vpn / socks proxy.

In other words, although what I want is:

```
client --> server --> vpn or socks server --> internet
```

What I'm getting instead is:

```
client --> server +---(server-native traffic)---> vpn2/socks --> internet
                  |
                  +---(client vpn traffic)----> internet
```

How can I achieve the result of forcing traffic from VPN clients into a second vpn or socks proxy?

**I'd like to do this transparently** - I can't control how the clients connect to the server, but I can control the server.

Comment: What are the routing table and firewall on the server, at the time it is exhibiting the problem?

Comment: All firewalls are temporarily disabled (to eliminate it as a problem). As for routing table, I've manually making a tuntap with subnet and default gateway to a foreign socks, as well as simply using openvpn as a client to connect to the foreign vpn server.

Comment: openvpn probably needs a static route to the server and a default gateway "inside" the second vpn defined in the configs.

Comment: @DanielWidrick wouldn't that require a change in the openvpn client config?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe the server can push routes. It might need a client. update though.

Comment: An example configuration is available at https://github.com/InternetForIran/InternetForIran .

Answer (score 1):

It's been five (5) years - almost to the day - since I posted this question (holy existential dread Batman!).  For the sake of anyone coming here from a web search:

### Use Wireguard

I was able to solve my problem a long time ago with [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/), compiled into the Linux kernel as of 5.6 (March 2020) and on. There are utilities available for mobile, desktop, and server platforms.

For those who don't want to use wireguard, or need a tor proxy, @HappyFace recently commented that example configurations exist [in a new Iran-focused github project](https://github.com/InternetForIran/InternetForIran). I have no idea if they work or not.

Wireguard has met all my needs. It's networking scheme is far simpler and easier to learn.